# Remove the Result wrapper from web service response?

Tags: web-services, xml-parsing, asmx, soap-client

I have a asmx webservice and it has a web method

```
    [WebMethod(Description = "Request for Read Stop Sale")]
    [SoapHeader("Security", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In)]
    [SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle=SoapParameterStyle.Bare,Action="OTA_HotelBookingRule")]
    public XmlDocument ReadStopSales()
    {
    ....
     I am getting some details from database and converting and transforming it into
    XML and then putting it into XmlDocument object and returning it...
    XmlResultDocument.LoadXml(results.ToString());
     return XmlResultDocument;
    }
```

the result which i am loading into XmlResultDocument has the root element  <OTA_HotelBookingRuleRS xmlns="">

I am testing this method by calling on SoapUI, it is giving me following result:

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <ReadStopSalesResult xmlns="http://localhost:6092/connectAPI.asmx">
         <OTA_HotelBookingRuleRS xmlns="">
            <RuleMessage HotelCode="5">
               <StatusApplication RatePlanCode="579_1" InvTypeCode="579" RatePlanCategory="BB"/>
               <BookingRules>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-15" End="2015-07-15">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-16" End="2015-07-16">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-17" End="2015-07-17">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-18" End="2015-07-18">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-19" End="2015-07-19">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-20" End="2015-07-20">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-21" End="2015-07-21">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-22" End="2015-07-22">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-23" End="2015-07-23">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-24" End="2015-07-24">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-25" End="2015-07-25">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-26" End="2015-07-26">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
               </BookingRules>
            </RuleMessage>
         </OTA_HotelBookingRuleRS>
      </ReadStopSalesResult>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I do not need the element <ReadStopSalesResult xmlns="http://localhost:6092/connectAPI.asmx"> 
In this element "ReadStopSales" is the webmethod name as you can see in C# code.

I want my result as below:

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
         <OTA_HotelBookingRuleRS xmlns="">
            <RuleMessage HotelCode="5">
               <StatusApplication RatePlanCode="579_1" InvTypeCode="579" RatePlanCategory="BB"/>
               <BookingRules>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-15" End="2015-07-15">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-16" End="2015-07-16">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-17" End="2015-07-17">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-18" End="2015-07-18">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-19" End="2015-07-19">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-20" End="2015-07-20">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-21" End="2015-07-21">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-22" End="2015-07-22">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-23" End="2015-07-23">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-24" End="2015-07-24">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-25" End="2015-07-25">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
                  <BookingRule Start="2015-07-26" End="2015-07-26">
                     <RestrictionStatus Restriction="Master" Status="Open"/>
                  </BookingRule>
               </BookingRules>
            </RuleMessage>
         </OTA_HotelBookingRuleRS>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

please help how to remove default result element ....

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing a `WebserviceHandler` and change the Response message. Sample code will look like :

```
public class ChangeMessageHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

@Override
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {

    Boolean outbound = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    if (!outbound) {
        try {
           SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();  
           soapMessage.getSOAPBody().appendChild(context.getMessage().getSOAPBody().getFirstChild().getFirstChild());
           context.setMessage(soapMessage); 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }        
    return true;
} }
```

Basically, I am trying to fetch the second node and adding it to new message.